# How do I search a very very large json file?

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have a enormous json file and I am trying to extract information form the file, but it is way to big to track down the path. Could I filter it using the id? [JSON code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BliFa4gEZivGHabLJtsgxdK1-OXe-hFi0D7lzVv3cdg/edit?usp=sharing) I need to pick up course names i.e.[image]

```
  let urlString = "Can't provide the url"
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString){
        if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []){
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            parseJSON(json)
        }
    }
}

func parseJSON(json: JSON){
    for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't look at the file and know which path to take? This sounds extremely odd. There are online sites that allow you to paste in JSON and they will format it nicely for you.

Comment: It's just a very very long json file and the info I need is in the middle

Comment: If you know which info you need, then do a find on the key and backtrack to get the path. Again, I would recommend pasting into a JSON service to have it nicely formatted.

Comment: I had to put the JSON code in a google doc, but I updated the question.

Comment: And what is it within this JSON file you are looking for specifically?

Comment: I provided a photo so in this case I need the text i.e. Study Hall, APENGLAN B

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112594/discussion-between-adam-h-and-johnson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a depth-first way of finding a given `JSON` object based on a predicate.

I made it into an extension:

```
extension JSON {

    func find(@noescape predicate: JSON -> Bool) -> JSON? {

        if predicate(self) {
            return self
        }
        else {
            if let subJSON = (dictionary?.map { $0.1 } ?? array) {
                for json in subJSON {
                    if let foundJSON = json.find(predicate) {
                        return foundJSON
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

For instance, to search for the `JSON` object with a given `id` field, such as in the question, you can use the method as such:

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
let predicate = {
    (json: JSON) -> Bool in
    if let jsonID = json["id"].string where jsonID == "plnMain_ddlClasses" {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
let foundJSON = json.find(predicate)
```

In this case, if you need to continue and find the classes you were looking for, you would want:

```
let classes = foundJSON?["children"].arrayValue.map {
    $0["html"].stringValue
}
```

**UPDATE — FIND ALL**

```
func findAll(@noescape predicate predicate: JSON -> Bool) -> [JSON] {
    var json: [JSON] = []
    if predicate(self) {
        json.append(self)
    }
    if let subJSON = (dictionary?.map{ $0.1 } ?? array) {
        // Not using `flatMap` to keep the @noescape attribute
        for object in subJSON {
            json += object.findAll(predicate: predicate)
        }
    }
    return json
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble importing all the "AssignmentClass". When I do `if let jsonID = json["class"].string where jsonID == "AssignmentClass" {
        return true
    }...`  I get only the first result (Study Hall), I understand why but still not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Whichever JSON object first satisfies the predicate is the one that will be returned. You may need to go a level or two up if the JSON that satisfies your predicate is in an array.

Comment: I don't understand the second part.

Comment: Which info are you looking for? I will better be able to help you.

Comment: So if you control f the json page "AssignmentClass" there should be 7 results within that array I need to extract the ["html"] with the class equal tp "sg-header-heading". i.e. the first one should be `"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t0020B - 33   STUDY HALL (INSTRUCT)\r\n\t\t\t\t"`

Comment: Ahhh, so there are multiple cases where your predicate works. You will have to use a different function for it. Try writing one.

Comment: That's what I thought, sweet. So I am assuming this is where the difference will occur in the other function? http://puu.sh/p1GGW/d7b28db134.png

Comment: I am not sure off the top of my head. We really should be doing this in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112632/discussion-between-johnson-and-adam-h).